# Thermodynamic versus kinetic reactions 2

Tags: organic-chemistry

I want to ask more following the previous Question. ([Thermodynamic versus kinetic reactions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47857/thermodynamic-versus-kinetic-reactions))

[image]

1. in this reaction below, is the first product 'kinetic product'? and second one is 'thermodynamic product' ?
2. upper pathway is acid/base reaction but doesn't seem reversible, thus looks like far from thermodynamics. but I learned acid/base reaction is about thermodynamics. what did I get wrong?

I'd appreciate any comments^_^

Comment: Note that it is possible that the thermodynamic and kinetic products are the same.

Comment: even when two different products can come up like a case above?

Comment: Yes, even so. An example is radical bromination. Radical bromination favors formation of the most stable radical (and by Hammond's postulate) this radical forms fastest.

Comment: if one product is kinetic and thermodynamic product at the same time, why would there any kind of other product?

Comment: @NKYu Because a mixture of products always has a lower Gibb's energy than a pure product.